# single word that means "self rescue"

Tags: single-word-requests

Of the survivor of, say, a plane crash where nobody came; they marched across the mountains and rescued themselves. The term I'm looking for is specifically associated with being in a bad place, traveling and being back in a normal/good place. Sort of like "extraction", but the other way around, in that the person was not pulled, they pushed them self.

Comment: *Self-rescue* is a single word for this but it is a term used in climbing.

Comment: "Self-rescue" is commonly used in adventure sports in the sense of extracting oneself from a dangerous or difficult and unplanned position. If there was a common alternative it would be used in those situations.

Comment: "saved him/her self"

Answer (score 3):

I like *extricate* as a replacement for *extract*, although it doesn't necessarily imply travel, and is not always used for oneself.

> : to free or remove (someone or something) from something (such as a trap or a difficult situation)

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extricate)

As in, *He extricated himself from the perils of the desert through quick thinking and sheer willpower.*

Answer (score 0):

The term *[soldier on](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/soldier-on)* is often used, even in non-military settings

> to persist in one's efforts in spite of difficulties, pressure, etc

*Collins*

This does not always suggest arrival at a happy ending, but it may be used in that context. Consider this example

> To continue to do something, especially when it is difficult or tedious; persevere: "As Russia decayed, these Siberians soldiered on, finding ways to live and enjoy life" (Jeffrey Tayler).

*[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=soldier%20on&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)*

Also possibly *[break through](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-through)*

> to achieve success, make a discovery, etc, esp after lengthy efforts

*Collins*

**Supplement:**

Also consider *[overcome](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=overcome)*

> To deal with successfully; prevail over; surmount: tried to overcome the obstacles of poverty.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

This type of usage is illustrated in the protest song popularized by Pete Seger, *[We Shall Overcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Shall_Overcome)*.

Comment: Which would work very well for not giving up, but does not suggest the getting out part.

Comment: There is a typo, mom-military.

Comment: @Rathony - Maybe his mother wore combat boots.